# Prevent Cascade insert JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this two class:

```
public class Order{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Status status;

}

public class Status{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;

  String description;

}
```

When i call Spring's JPARepository to save the Order, jpa try to save save a new Status row, but in fact i want only save the relationship between Order and Status.
My status table should never change.
How can i prevent the second insert in "Status" table?

Exception:

```
"org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

"Order" table has ID(PK), StatusId(FK)
"Status" table has ID(PK), description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the operations to cascade in the relational annotation, see [cascade()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#cascade()), like

`@ManyToOne(fetch=..., cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})`

Notice that we specify *which* operations to cascade, implying to *not* cascade the other operations.

Answer (score 0):

If status can have multiple orders you should move your association control to status class and have list of orders there with oneToMany annotation. Also, it is preferred that you should use bidirectional associations instead unidirectional. To sum this up in your case proper mapping would look like this:

```
public class Order{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Status status;
}


public class Status{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="status")
    List<Order> orders;
}
```

Comment: are you sure? A order has only one status, but many order's can have the same status.

Comment: If status can have multiple orders you should move your association control to status class and have list of orders there with oneToMany annotation.

Answer (score -3):

THis is a very basic concept. Since u r using @GeneratedValue, it will generate new id everytime u do save and create new row.

Comment: Even without `@GeneratedValue`, the problema still the same.